# Filtering pages to redirect to 404 in .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

I have a site that use to have a search engine script on it, that has been removed and replaced with new content.

Every so often the site gets flooded with requests like:

```
/index.php?page=search/web/appdojo.com

/index.php?page=search/web/2tu.us

/index.php?page=search/emailafriend&url=http%253A%252F%252F

/index.php?page=user/viewcomments/images/82e10127b84ee2750c
```

This then causes a huge amount of processes to start up and then we have problems with the hosting provider.

I'm thinking I should be able to stop these in `.htaccess` before `index.php` is called but haven't figured out a `regex` expression to do that but to let the rest of the `index.php` url's to pass through OK.

Can anyone help out?  -thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you include PHP in your tags, it would be far easier to simply show a 404 error on the index.php and make it seem to be an error.  So you can put this before **everything** on the index.php page:

```
if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    include('404.php'); //Whatever your 404 error page is
    exit();
}
```

Comment: I already tried that, but index.php starts a process, I need to stop it from running the index.php file.  I think I have to do it in .htaccess?

Comment: The `exit();` should kill everything else.

Answer (score 0):

if your index page is not using the page variable at all, you could try blocking all url's that have the page param in the url

```
RewriteRule ^index.php?page= /Your_404_page.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is better to stop them at .htaccess stage to prevent loading PHP. Here is the rule that will work for you in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?page= [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=304,L]
```